# How to measure CPU voltage on a 570 motherboard with lm_sensors?

Tags: arch-linux, hardware, amd, sensors

I am trying, and failing, to determine my CPU's Vcore voltage. My CPU is a Ryzen 3700X in an [ASRock 570M Pro](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/X570M%20Pro4/#Specification) motherboard, using Arch Linux (fully updated).

I downloaded the `lm_sensors` package, ran `sensors-detect` and accepted all scans, and then ran `watch sensors`. My output when the CPU is idle with only the terminal running is attached below.

Under load, the only voltage value that changes is in0, reaching up to about 720 mV (on one core at 100%). Some guides online suggest that in0 is usually the Vcore, but it is far too low for this to be the case here. The 3700X has a normal operating voltage of [between .2 V and 1.5 V](https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/cbls9g/the_final_word_on_idle_voltages_for_3rd_gen_ryzen/), with the latter being reached when a single core is boosting at max load. (The temperatures and fan speeds appear correct based on my testing.)

What can do I to correctly read my Vcore? Thank you.

```
amdgpu-pci-0800
Adapter: PCI adapter
vddgfx:        1.11 V  
fan1:        1471 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, max = 4100 RPM)
edge:         +27.0°C  (crit = +91.0°C, hyst = -273.1°C)
power1:       47.25 W  (cap = 180.00 W)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tdie:         +29.8°C  (high = +70.0°C)
Tctl:         +29.8°C  

nct6798-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:                    96.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +1.74 V)
in1:                     1.66 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in2:                     3.46 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in3:                     3.33 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in4:                     1.83 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in5:                     1.10 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in6:                     1.20 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in7:                     3.46 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in8:                     3.28 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in9:                     1.66 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in10:                    1.02 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in11:                  624.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in12:                    1.04 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in13:                  928.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in14:                  904.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
fan1:                   895 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:                  1023 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:                   752 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan4:                   629 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan5:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan6:                  3161 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan7:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
SYSTIN:                 +30.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, hyst = +95.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
CPUTIN:                 +26.5°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN0:                +15.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN1:                -61.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN2:                +13.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN3:                +31.0°C    sensor = thermistor
SMBUSMASTER 1:          +51.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, hyst = +95.0°C)
SMBUSMASTER 0:          +29.5°C  
PCH_CHIP_CPU_MAX_TEMP:   +0.0°C  
PCH_CHIP_TEMP:           +0.0°C  
intrusion0:            ALARM
intrusion1:            ALARM
beep_enable:           disabled
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you currently have any `compute in0` statements in your `/etc/sensors.conf`, `/etc/sensors3.conf` or `/etc/sensors.d/*.conf` that would apply to sensor chip `nct6798-isa-0290`? If you have, comment them out and run `sensors --set` as root.

Then look at the value again.

According to my old notes (probably scribbled up from a datasheet found who-knows-where in the internet), the Nuvoton NC6798D's voltage inputs have a range of 0 .. 2.048 V with a 8-bit accuracy, and a number of inputs have a built-in 2x divider to extend the range. These inputs with the range doubler are `in2`, `in3`, `in7`, `in8` and `in9`, possibly also `in0`. That would mean that the lowest significant bit in each voltage register would signify a change of either 8 or 16 mV, depending on whether the input has the divider or not.

The voltage sensors with the built-in divider are integral to the chip, and have default designations:

- in2 = AVSB
- in3 = 3Vcc (normal 3.3V rail)
- in7 = 3Vsb (stand-by 3.3V input)
- in8 = Vbat (CMOS battery voltage)
- in9 = Vtt (processor memory controller voltage?)

It sort of looks like something may be applying an extra 2x divider to your `in0` value. If so, adding something like

```
chip "nct6798-isa-0290"    # add this if it does not already exist
    compute in0 @*2, @/2   # then add this line _after_ the previous one
```

to your lm-sensors configuration should fix it.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably it. A similar multiplier appears in several of the provided config files for other boards. I'm still curious whether that's guesswork or whether it's been confirmed from a data sheet, though. (I tried to upvote your answer also but do not yet have enough reputation.)

Comment: According to my notes, the datasheet (of questionable provenance) indicated the range doubler in all those mentioned `inN` lines, including `in0`. However, the Linux driver source code (which is shared between several Nuvoton chip models) only takes it into account on `in2`, `in3`, `in7`, `in8` and `in9`. Maybe `in0` has the doubler in the NC6798D model only, or maybe the datasheet or my notes had an error.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: It seems that motherboard manufacturers do not want to share information how the monitoring is actually built. For example, ASUS B550 motherboard uses chip `nct6798-isa-0290` and it has 15 voltage measurements of which maybe 10 would require some unknown resistor setup data to output actual hardware voltages (-12, +12, -5, +5 etc). When all the measurements are in range +0.24...+1.1V it's hard to tell which is actually connected to which actual voltage rail. Without correct setup, the best you can do is to monitor changes relative to original.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen Indeed. But if you have the chip datasheet, you can know the precision of the measurements at the HW monitoring chip. Then you can watch the measurements in the BIOS menu or in a vendor-provided Windows monitoring tool, and look for the size of the smallest detectable fluctuations in the displayed values. If the smallest fluctuation seems to be e.g. 6x the nominal precision of the chip, you'll know that there is probably a resistor setup that acts as a 6:1 voltage divider. Once you know the multipliers, try them for each measurement channel and see what makes sense.